# Returned string of getline(ifstream, line) is empty

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

My problem in a larger project is that `std::getline()` returns an empty string. Here's my code snippet:

```cpp
int main() {

    std::ifstream reading_file;
    reading_file.open("smalldata-n.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::string line;

    std::getline(reading_file, line);
    std::cout << "1. first line is: " << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first line has very important information for the rest of the code.

At first, I thought maybe the problem is from the data format but when using another simple text file I encounter the same problem again.

I can't see what I have missed and it looks fine according to other samples on the web.

Comment: Make a habit of always checking the stream state after each operation. Starting point is the method `good()` or `operator bool ()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, it fails. (good bit is zero, return value of stream.good() is zero and fail bit is 1. But that's just a simple text file why is this happening?

Comment: The file not found.

Comment: I created another text file in the directory but the situation is still the same..

Comment: Try to learn what is application working path.

Comment: Oh god! I used to work with Java, Python, and Matlab and in all of them upon creating the project this working directory was handled. I can't believe my problem could be solved that simple!
Thanks!

Comment: Trust me on this one: with the right IDE you would have had the same problem with all three other languages. This isn't a C++ thing, it's an operating system thing.

Comment: You're right, I mean as I recall, I set this working directory upon creating the projects in those IDEs but this time in CLion I didn't encounter it at first place so I forgot to set it.